How many of you with addresses in your profiles have actually collected tips?
For many years now, it's been popular to post a crypto address for "tips" if you are participating in any online bitcoin community. 
I've seen a few of the users here do it. I'm wondering if any of them have actually collected any tips. 

This is basically a straw poll, so I figured meta would be okay.
